# Check String for Uppercase letter and find position

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching, stringtokenizer

I need to check if in my String "sir" i have some uppercase letters, if so, i need to assign the value of that letter to another string and then to delete the letter. my first part looks like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sir);
    boolean b = m.find();
```

so that i check if there is any uppercase letter, then i need to add assigning & deleting. i am not sure if this works. also i found 
 another way:

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sir);

    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String a = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if(a.equals(a.toUpperCase())) {
            upper = a; 
        }
    }
```

upper returns null everytime, even though sir = cL

does anyone know a way to:

1. get uppercase letter & positon from string
2. delete it

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all UPPERCASE letters from a string:

```
String repl = sir.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "");
```

To copy all UPPERCASE letters from a string to another string:

```
String upper = sir.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "");
```

Comment: i think that's the most general solution and it fits best for me, as i will have maximum one uppercase letter per string. the copy all uppercase works, but the remove one is the same, and it does not remove, leading me to an infinite loop in my recursive method. if you could please tell me how to remove all UPPERCASE letter you would totally solve my issue.

Comment: Actually `sir.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "")` does replace all upper case letters with empty string. You just need to make sure to use the replaced string as shown in example above since original string remains unchanged since String is immutable.

Comment: yes. thank you very much. just did

`sir = sir.replaceAll("[a-z]+", "");`  
 yes, lowercase.
i dont really understand why this happens, by i get my final string 'sir' only in lowercase. Thank you.

Comment: It should be: `sir = sir.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "");` and make sure to do it after `String upper = sir.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "");`

Comment: ' String upper = sir.replaceAll("[^A-Z]+", "");
        sir = sir.replaceAll("[^a-z]+", "");

        Log.v(TAG, "String upper " + upper); ' 

here is the log.V : http://pastebin.com/j2MD0zmz 

mby you would understand why it works

Comment: Actually `sir = sir.replaceAll("[^a-z]+", "");` is same as `sir = sir.replaceAll("[A-Z]+", "");`

Comment: i tried, it goes into an infinite loop. anyway thank you very much for your time and help. but in case you wish know why i get the right answer the wrong way,
here is the full code, maybe i missed something: http://pastebin.com/WQ5CUTY8 and here is the result. 
logCat: http://pastebin.com/T6tUTVdx

and here is logcat with a-z lowercase: http://pastebin.com/475rEqVL

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the capital letters in a string:

```
String inputString;
```

`String outputString = "";`

`for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    c = inputString.charAt(i);
    ouptutString += Character.isUpperCase(c) ? c + " " : ""; 
}`

Comment: doesn't look like java

Comment: oops i thought your post was C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try "guava" libriaries. There you can find set of classes for string manipulation. Among them CharMatcher (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher)

simple code example can be:

```
 String string = "ABcdEFgh45";
 String withoutUpperCase = CharMatcher.JAVA_UPPER_CASE.removeFrom(string);
 //returns cdgh45
```